# How to scroll to a specific textField element in ScrollRect with Unity scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, keyboard, scrollrect

I am Beginner in unity. As I am trying to create a form in the single scene with multiple textField. For keyboard i need to enable the next button also if i select the last textfield in the scene screen should be move to the particular textfield. In iOS we have the TPKeyboardAvoidScrolling framework to reduce the work. Do we have any framework for this or anyone please suggest some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your textview all have same size, you can simply change position of "container".

Let's say your textviews have a size of 100x50. If you want to go to the 5th element, your `localPosition` would be `Vector3.Up * 50 * 5`.

Comment: I mean "all textviews has same size".

Comment: Next option in keyboard how can i enable

Comment: @smyl Instead of leaving a comment on your answer, edit your answer. Answers are editable for this reason.